# To get nearest li class name on click of anchor tag element using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get the `li` class name on click of anchor tag `<a>`

```
<li class="active">
      <a href="#pending" data-toggle="tab" title="Pending" onclick="loadBolttCommunityData('pending')">
          <span class="round-tabs two">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></span> 
      </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get parent li using jquery `parent` method and its class name by `attr` method.

```
<li class="active">
    <a class="foo" href="#pending" data-toggle="tab" title="Pending" onclick="loadBolttCommunityData('pending')">
     <span class="round-tabs two">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>
      </span> 
     </a>
</li>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.foo').on('click',function(){
       $(this).parent('li').attr('class');
    })
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Aniket, i am try your script & getting "dropdown user user-menu" which is not define in HTML as well as this class name is wrong.  If i am use this $(this).parent('li').attr('class'); then it return the undefined error.

Comment: give your a tag a particular class name and replace 'a' with your '.classname'. See the edited answer

Comment: @RajeevVarshney accepting the answer can help other users to trust the answer